Message : System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Mutex System.Threading.Mutex.OpenExisting
We are migrating the .Net framework project to .Net core. In this project there was a reference to a external dll. so we have created a .Net Core application and referred the external library (ViewerLib4 dll). When I tried to call a method from the referred dll it throws the below error.
Message : System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Mutex System.Threading.Mutex.OpenExisting(System.String, System.Security.AccessControl.MutexRights)'.
at FSCProLib.HostConnection.PerformCall(_CALLER* pCaller, Void* pvCmd, Void* pvResponse)
at FSCProLib.HostConnection.ConnectPS(SByte* xdatstr, UInt16* xstrlen, UInt16 PSPos, Int32 userTracking)
at FSCProLib.HostConnection.connect(String type)
at FSCProLib.HostConnection.connect()
at BenefitPlan.API.Service.BasicService.OpenConn() in C:\Users\prabulk\source\repos\BenefitPlan.API\Service\BasicService.cs:line 61
Is this due to the .Net core compatability with the referred dll in .Net framework?
